# how to take the date of birth of the user using date picker from angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am new to angular material and i am finding some issues over there.
the output is coming perfectly but when i click on the month and year(jul 2016) it should be displayed the entire years so that the user can select his Dob.but it was not dispalying or not even clickable. whereas it is perfectly working in angular material docs.i had given images of date pickers below. please go through that.

can any one hep me?
thanks in advance .

### in html

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate">
</md-datepicker>
```

[image] not working this is my output image

[image: this is the output i need] this is output of angular material docs

here is the working example [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNLyGJ?editors=1010)

Comment: sure just now i have give my codepen

Comment: what i mean  actually if  suppose i want to select a date of 1994-04-05 it is not directly working i have to scroll up to find the year of 1994 in my application where as when i noticed in angular material docs it is working perfectly there is current month and year as i highlighted in above image is clickable so that you directly to the year 1994. but not working in my application. i dont know what happened

Comment: yeah thats what i mean. but that functionality is not working in my app. i followed the same docs as angular material given. can you help me over here.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but when I asked for a working example I meant a working example of *your* html and code :-) Could you create a CodePen with that? (I've deleted my previous comments to reduce the amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to select year in angularjs datepicker at the moment.

But consider using jQuery `datepicker`: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/

Comment: It's against AngularJS best practise to mix jQuery with AngularJS.